# Salesforce SOQL query return all values including NULL

Tags: salesforce, soql

I have a simple SOQL query:

```
select Count(ID), CampaignId, Campaign.Name 
from CampaignMember 
where CampaignId in ('701U0000000MVoQ', '701U0000000MLFR', '701U0000000MVoL') 
group by CampaignId, Campaign.Name
```

The result of the query brings back 2 records as there are contacts in two of the campaign member lists.

I would also like to bring back the 3rd record in which the count will be 0. Is there a way to do this in SOQL, I don't believe there is an ISNULL() function that can be used on the select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any special reason why you need an aggregate query? One way to do it would be to use relationships, like that:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Id FROM CampaignMembers)
FROM Campaign
WHERE Id IN ('701U0000000MVoQ', '701U0000000MLFR', '701U0000000MVoL')
```

Later in code it can be accessed like that

```
List<Campaign> campaigns = [Id, Name, (SELECT Id FROM CampaignMembers)
FROM Campaign
WHERE Id IN ('701U0000000MVoQ', '701U0000000MLFR', '701U0000000MVoL')];

for(Campaign c : campaigns){
    System.debug(c.Name + ': ' + c.CampaignMembers.size());
}
```

Comment: Thanks eyescream, that makes much more sense than my original way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a additional part to your soql query called "Having". Having is like a Where Clause

```
select Count(ID), CampaignId, Campaign.Name 
from CampaignMember 
where CampaignId in ('701U0000000MVoQ', '701U0000000MLFR', '701U0000000MVoL')
group by CampaignId, Campaign.Name 
HAVING COUNT(ID) >0
```

Having is like a Where clause but the HAVING clause only applies to columns that also appear in the GROUP BY.

Comment: `HAVING` can only limit the amount of rows even further, how do you plan to use it to expand them?